# Use props in pressable in react native for navigation

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, navigation

I am new to react native. What I want to achieve is that I want to navigate between screen while using pressable. What i have done is I have already created pressable button components inside buttons.js file what I want right now is that when I call that component inside of a file  I want to pass screen name as a prop to that button component and navigate between screen using that main component. In short what i mean is whenever a screen name is passed from different file it act according to that and instead I don`t have to create multiple navigation inside each file.

E.g
Inside Home file

```
<ButtonXsPrimary
   title='Login'
/>
```

Inside Buttons.js file

```
const ButtonXsPrimary = (prop) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <>
      <Pressable style={[style.buttonXs, Color.bgSecondry]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(prop)} >
        <Text style={[Color.White, style.buttonsTextSm]}>{prop.title}</Text>
        
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
};
```

The same title prop is used for navigation

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can do this way,

1. You need to pass navigation and route name as a prop inside your ButtonXsPrimary like

<ButtonXsPrimary
title="Login"
navigation={navigation}
routeName={'YourRouteName'}
/>

2. Access the props

   onPress={() => prop.navigation.navigate(prop.routeName)}

Comment: @anonymous421, if you found this answer useful, please accept the same.